# If I left join table2 to table1, how I can I call on the IDs in table1 that don't appear in table2 within a CASE or IF Statement?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am writing an IF/Case statement that requires me to identify all the Ids from and `ID` column in `Table1` that don't appear in a 2nd table `Table2` which is left joined on to `Table1` on the `ID` Column, And based on that IF statement I would like to produce a binary column called `Missing` with 1s, 0s.

Table1

| ID | Region |
| --- | --- |
| a | US |
| b | US |
| c | Mexico |
| d | Japan |

Table2

| ID | Years |
| --- | --- |
| a | 5 |
| d | 10 |

After joining this is what I have:

| ID | Region | Years |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | US | 5 |
| b | US | null |
| c | Mexico | null |
| d | Japan | 10 |

The final outcome should be:

| ID | Region | Years | Missing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | US | 5 | 0 |
| b | US | null | 1 |
| c | Mexico | null | 1 |
| d | Japan | 10 | 0 |

I don't know how to Identify those specific Ids in the IF or CASE statement but the rest of the query I can write. I tried to write

`IF(Table1.ID NOT IN Table2.ID, 1, 0) As Missing`

but that did not work (some sort of unnest issue)

Comment: Could you add sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Ok I added the sample data and expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.ID IS NULL AS Missing
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID;
```

Using the `IF()` function we can try:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, IF(t2.ID IS NULL, 1, 0) AS Missing
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID;
```

Comment: how do I write this in an IF or CASE statement , like I attempted to do above?

Comment: Check the updated answer above.